# How to determine if Image is already drawn in HTML Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, image-loading

supposed i have an image /site/image1.jpg upon drawing this to the canvas it would be something like this.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "/site/image1.jpg";
image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(image,x,y);
}
```

Assuming my internet connection is so slow how would i know that the image was already drawn on the canvas?

Thanks.

Comment: to know if the image has finished loading, you can check `image.complete`. But the best solution is to add a callback in the onload event :  `image.onload = doTheNextOperations`

Comment: You would need to create a custom class which would have a `bool`. You could set the `bool` to `true` when it has been drawn.

Answer (score 1):

To workout if the image has been draw keep a flag or mark the image.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "blah.foo";
image.drawn = false;  // Add a property to indicate if the image has been drawn
image.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
    image.drawn = true;  // flag it as drawn
}
// then later you if you want to know if its been drawn
if(image.drawn){
    console.log("Yes its been drawn.");
}
```

Comment: If the draw operation occurs onload of the image, then just checking if it's been loaded is enough. (image.complete is a boolean) But IMO this question reveals a problem in the code design, that should not be workarounded by such flag hacks